# Looping through .json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loops, for-loop

I have a .JSON file full of data similar of this:

```
[
{
    "scan_type": "nexpose",
    "date_time": "2016-07-18 18:21:44",
    "source_address": "1111",
    "source_lat": "22.555260",
    "source_lng": "-15.084420",
},   
...
]
```

And I wrote a script that will convert this data to an object, here is my script:

```
let obj = require('./dataOut.json');
var fs = require('fs');

//json variables
let scan_type = obj[0].scan_type;
let date_time = obj[0].date_time;
let source_address = obj[0].source_address;
let source_lat = obj[0].source_lat;
let source_lng = obj[0].source_lng;

//source contains the new object
var source = {
    id: source_lat + source_lng,
    "source-lat": source_lat,
    "source-lng": source_lng,
    "source_address": source_address,
    x: {
        valueOf: function () {
            var latlng = [
                source_lat,
                source_lng
            ];
            var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
            return xy[0];
        }
    },
    y: {
        valueOf: function () {
            var latlng = [
                source_lat,
                source_lng
            ];
            var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
            return xy[1];
        }
    }
}
//write out to file and stringify
fs.writeFile('./parentSource.json', JSON.stringify(source, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

As you can see, currently I have everything set to the first element [0] from my data file for testing. But I need to change that to where it will loop through each element.

Normally I'd just use a [foreach](http://pastebin.com/3kNTaQET) loop, but that has been unsuccessful.

How can I add a loop that will go through each .JSON object and add the values to my script, so that my output file will contain all the newly formatted data?

For clarification, I want to the result to be written as a result to an array, in one file output.

Also: my current code works just fine, but only for the first element[0], I just need to find a way to loop through the rest of the elements from the .JSON, and include them in my output

Comment: You can use the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to parse JSON to JS Object.

Comment: Where is `destination` defined?

Comment: Do you want each object written to the output file separately, or written as a JSON array to the file? Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: *Normally I'd just use a foreach loop, but that has been unsuccessful*. Why? What did you try?

Comment: @10100111001 Unless I'm mistaken, `let obj = require('./dataOut.json');` is already doing the parsing and populating the result to `obj`. And `obj.forEach()` should work.

Comment: `obj.forEach(o => { /* let scan_type = o.scan_type; ... */ });` should work

Comment: @10100111001, Arnauld: yeah, at least in Node.js you can require JSON files directly

Comment: @Arnauld Ah yes, that is correct.

Comment: @rgoliveira in for foreach loop, I linked it in the original code. I essentially used that, and tried to increment the index through each iteration of the file.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I didn't add destination because it is a copy of "var source" except it's named "var destination" . Thanks! Also I'll add some clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, try the `forEach` with an arrow function. Something like this:

```
let obj = require('./dataOut.json');
var fs = require('fs');

const source = [];

obj.forEach(o => {
  //json variables
  const scan_type = o.scan_type;
  const date_time = o.date_time;
  const source_address = o.source_address;
  const source_lat = o.source_lat;
  const source_lng = o.source_lng;

  //source contains the new object
  source.push({
    id: source_lat + source_lng,
    "source-lat": source_lat,
    "source-lng": source_lng,
    "source_address": source_address,
    x: {
      valueOf: function () {
        var latlng = [
          source_lat,
          source_lng
        ];
        var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
        return xy[0];
      }
    },
    y: {
      valueOf: function () {
        var latlng = [
          source_lat,
          source_lng
        ];
        var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
        return xy[1];
      }
    }
  });
});

//write out to file and stringify
fs.writeFile('./parentSource.json', JSON.stringify(source, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

The `o`, at each iteration, will be an item of the array in your `./dataOut.json` file.

Comment: That works! Good solution, thanks a bunch. Sorry, I missed your earlier comment.

Comment: Note that I changed some of your `var` and `let` keywords to `const`. You should read a bit about them, as it makes it easier to understand the code and to tell the interpreter what you want from each member: [JavaScript ES6 Variable Declarations with let and const](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/es6-variable-declarations/). Cheers.